# Delete substrings from a list of strings

Tags: python, list, substring

I have a list

```
l = ['abc', 'abcdef', 'def', 'defdef', 'polopolo']
```

I'm trying to delete strings whose superstring is already in the list. In this case, the result should be:

```
['abcdef', 'defdef', 'polopolo']
```

I have written the code:

```
l=['abc','abcdef','def','defdef','polopolo']
res=['abc','abcdef','def','defdef','polopolo']
for each in l:
    l1=[x for x in l if x!=each]
    for other in l1:
        if each in other:
            res.remove(each)
```

but it doesnt seem to work. I have read that we cannot remove from the list while iterating over it. Hence the copy `res`, while `l` is my original list.

Comment: Your code would have worked if you broke out of the loop immediately after `res.remove(each)` :) For an efficient way to do this, please check my answer :)

Comment: pretty stupid mistake on my part now that you have explained it. :) Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
l=['abc','abcdef','def','defdef','polopolo']
print [j for i, j in enumerate(l) if all(j not in k for k in l[i + 1:])]
# ['abcdef', 'defdef', 'polopolo']
```

We can speed it up a very little, by sorting the list before

```
l = sorted(l, key = len)
print [j for i, j in enumerate(l) if all(j not in k for k in l[i + 1:])]
```

As [@Ashwini Chaudhary mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221878/python-delete-substrings-from-list-of-strings/22221956?noredirect=1#comment33741159_22221956), if you want to retain the duplicate strings, then you can do this

```
l = ['abc','defghi' 'abcdef','def','defdef','defdef', 'polopolo']
l = sorted(l, key = len)
print [j for i,j in enumerate(l) if all(j == k or (j not in k) for k in l[i+1:])]
# ['defdef', 'defdef', 'polopolo', 'defghiabcdef']
```

Comment: Try with `['abc','defghi' 'abcdef','def','defdef','defdef', 'polopolo']`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I get `['defghiabcdef', 'defdef', 'polopolo']`. Is that wrong?

Comment: Duh! missed `,` after `'defghi'`, BTW `'defdef'` count decreased to 1.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Strictly speaking, a string is a substring of itself, right? ;)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. :) But just in case OP wants to keep both occurrences then a small change is required in the `all` condition.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks for checking the code and the suggestions yaar :)

Comment: Yes @thefourtheye.. your solution works, but can you point out why mine does not work?

Comment: @user2058724 Your code would have worked if you broke out of the loop immediately after `res.remove(each)` :)

Comment: @thefourtheye The first one does not work if the substring follows the bigger string. Try with `['abc', 'abcdef', 'defdef', 'def', 'polopolo']`. It is solved if the list is always sorted by len before execution.