# Obtain a list containing string elements excluding elements prefixed with any other element from initial list

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, filtering

I have some trouble with filtering a list of strings. I found a similar question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221878/python-delete-substrings-from-list-of-strings) but is not what i need.

The input list is:

```
l = ['ab', 'xc', 'abb', 'abed', 'sdfdg', 'abfdsdg', 'xccc']
```

and the expected result is

```
['ab', 'xc', 'sdfdg']
```

The order of the items in the result is not important

The filter function must be fast because the size of list is big

My current solution is

```
l = ['ab', 'xc', 'abb', 'abed', 'sdfdg', 'abfdsdg', 'xccc']
for i in range(0, len(l) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(l)):
        if l[j].startswith(l[i]):
            l[j] = l[i]
        else:
            if l[i].startswith(l[j]):
                l[i] = l[j]

print list(set(l))
```

**EDIT**

After multiple tests with a big input data, list with 1500000 strings, my best solution for this is:

```
def filter(l):
    if l==[]:
        return []
    l2=[]
    l2.append(l[0])
    llen = len(l)
    k=0
    itter = 0
    while k<llen:
        addkelem = ''
        j=0
        l2len = len(l2)
        while j<l2len:
            if (l2[j].startswith(l[k]) and l[k]!= l2[j]):
                l2[j]=l[k]
                l.remove(l[k])
                llen-=1
                j-=1
                addkelem = ''
                continue
            if (l[k].startswith(l2[j])):
                addkelem = ''
                break
            elif(l[k] not in l2):
                addkelem = l[k]
            j+=1
        if addkelem != '':
            l2.append(addkelem)
            addkelem = ''
        k+=1
    return l2
```

for which the execution time is around of 213 seconds

[Sample imput data](http://soft2u.ro/out.7z) - each line is a string in list

Comment: is the resulting order important? I mean should the algorithm be stable and keep the original order?

Comment: The output order is not important, the filtering and execution time is critical

Comment: checkout my answer, it takes about 1.5 seconds for 1.500.000 elements on my 2.7 GHz computer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This algorithm completes the task in 0.97 second on my computer, with [the input file submitted by the author (154MB)](http://soft2u.ro/out.txt):

```
l.sort()

last_str = l[0]
filtered = [last_str]
app      = filtered.append

for str in l:
    if not str.startswith(last_str):
        last_str = str
        app(str)

# Commented because of the massive amount of data to print.
# print filtered
```

The algorithm is simple: first sort the list lexicographically, then search for the first string which isn't prefixed by the very first one of the list, then search the next one which isn't prefixed by the last unprefixed one, etc.

If the list is already sorted (your example file seems to be already sorted), you can remove the `l.sort()` line, which will result in a O(n) complexity in both time and memory.

Comment: Quick and easy. Is the fastest solution, i like this

Comment: If optimized and made into a function this is probably the best approach.

Comment: Excellent solution. The point is that `append` takes constant time.

Comment: Much simpler than my solution, I was way over complicating the issue, you would need to `map(str.rstrip..` the file object to get the correct result which is 251

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Thanks for the advice, but the author requested that the input was a list, and that the output was a list too. And I'm not sure if keeping the whole file in RAM while performing actions on filtered elements is really optimal.

Comment: @BenoitEsnard, in python2 using itertools.imap and the generator expression is slightly faster. The file has to be in ram as that is what you are sorting. open the file, sort the content then get the len of the list your code returns, it will be equal to the length of the file because no string startswith a substring that has `\r\n` at the end

Comment: (a) This solution is excellent. (b) There is a solution that only keeps the "prepends" in memory, and not the whole list in memory, no? Possibly there are no prepends, in which case the whole file ends up in memory. But if the size of the input file dwarfs the output file, there is an even better solution, no? If you agree, and want to see it, I'll code it up.

Comment: You need [sorted containers](http://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html) for the best possible implementation

Comment: Your solution is based on the same principle as mine, but is so concise that I can't even believe this works. Kudos.

Answer (score 8):

You can  group the items by first letter and just search the sublists, no string can start with  a substring unless it has at least the same first letter:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def find(l):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    # group by first letter
    for ele in l:
        d[ele[0]].append(ele)
    for val in d.values():
        for v in val:
            # check each substring in the sublist
            if not any(v.startswith(s) and v != s  for s in val):
                yield v

print(list(find(l)))
['sdfdg', 'xc', 'ab']
```

This correctly filters the words, as you can see from the code below that the reduce function does not, `'tool'` should not be in the output:

```
In [56]: l = ["tool",'ab',"too", 'xc', 'abb',"toot", 'abed',"abel", 'sdfdg', 'abfdsdg', 'xccc',"xcew","xrew"]

In [57]: reduce(r,l)
Out[57]: ['tool', 'ab', 'too', 'xc', 'sdfdg', 'xrew']

In [58]: list(find(l))
Out[58]: ['sdfdg', 'too', 'xc', 'xrew', 'ab']
```

It also does it efficiently:

```
In [59]: l = ["".join(sample(ascii_lowercase, randint(2,25))) for _ in range(5000)]

In [60]: timeit reduce(r,l)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.12 s per loop

In [61]: timeit list(find(l))
1 loops, best of 3: 203 ms per loop

In [66]: %%timeit
..... result = []
....: for element in lst:
....:   is_prefixed = False
....:   for possible_prefix in lst:
....:     if element is not possible_prefix and  element.startswith(possible_prefix):
....:       is_prefixed = True
....:       break
....:   if not is_prefixed:
....:     result.append(element)
....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 4.39 s per loop

In [92]: timeit list(my_filter(l))
1 loops, best of 3: 2.94 s per loop
```

If you know the minimum string length is always > 1 you can optimise further, again if the minimum length string is `2` then a word has to have a minimum of the first two letters in common:

```
def find(l):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    # find shortest length string to use as key length
    mn = len(min(l, key=len))
    for ele in l:
        d[ele[:mn]].append(ele)

    for val in d.values():
        for v in val:
            if not any(v.startswith(s) and v != s for s in val):
                yield v


In [84]: timeit list(find(l))
100 loops, best of 3: 14.6 ms per loop
```

Lastly if you have dupes you may want to filter out the duplicated words from your list but you need to keep them to compare:

```
from collections import defaultdict,Counter

def find(l):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    mn = len(min(l, key=len))
    cn = Counter(l)
    for ele in l:
        d[ele[:mn]].append(ele)
    for val in d.values():
        for v in val:
            if not any(v.startswith(s) and v != s for s in val): 
                # make sure v is not a dupe
                if cn[v] == 1:
                    yield v
```

So if speed is important, an implementation using some variation of the code above is going to be significantly faster than your naive approach. There is also more data stored in memory so you should also take the into account.

To save memory we can create a counter for each val/sublist so we only store a single counter dict of  words at a time:

```
def find(l):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    mn = len(min(l, key=len))
    for ele in l:
        d[ele[:mn]].append(ele)
    for val in d.values():
        # we only need check each grouping of words for dupes
        cn = Counter(val)
        for v in val:
            if not any(v.startswith(s) and v != s for s in val):
                if cn[v] == 1:
                    yield v
```

creating a dict each loop adds 5ms so still < 20ms for 5k words.

The reduce method should work if the data is sorted:

```
 reduce(r,sorted(l)) # -> ['ab', 'sdfdg', 'too', 'xc', 'xrew']
```

To make the difference clear between the behaviour:

```
In [202]: l = ["tool",'ab',"too", 'xc', 'abb',"toot", 'abed',
             "abel", 'sdfdg', 'abfdsdg', 'xccc',"xcew","xrew","ab"]

In [203]: list(filter_list(l))
Out[203]: ['ab', 'too', 'xc', 'sdfdg', 'xrew', 'ab']

In [204]: list(find(l))
Out[204]: ['sdfdg', 'too', 'xc', 'xrew', 'ab', 'ab']

In [205]: reduce(r,sorted(l))
Out[205]: ['ab', 'sdfdg', 'too', 'xc', 'xrew']

In [206]: list(find_dupe(l))
Out[206]: ['too', 'xrew', 'xc', 'sdfdg']

In [207]: list(my_filter(l))
Out[207]: ['sdfdg', 'xrew', 'too', 'xc']
In [208]: "ab".startswith("ab")
Out[208]: True
```

So `ab` is repeated twice so using a set or a dict without keeping track of how may times `ab` appeared would mean we consider that there was no other element that satisfied the condition `ab` `"ab".startswith(other ) == True`, which we can see is incorrect.

You can also use itertools.groupby to group based on the min index size:

```
def find_dupe(l):
    l.sort()
    mn = len(min(l, key=len))
    for k, val in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x[:mn]):
        val = list(val)
        for v in val:
            cn = Counter(val)
            if not any(v.startswith(s) and v != s for s in val) and cn[v] == 1:
                yield v
```

Based on your comments then we can adjust my first code if you don't think `"dd".startswith("dd")` should be True with repeated elements:

```
l = ['abbb', 'xc', 'abb', 'abed', 'sdfdg', 'xc','abfdsdg', 'xccc', 'd','dd','sdfdg', 'xc','abfdsdg', 'xccc', 'd','dd']


def find_with_dupe(l):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    # group by first letter
    srt = sorted(set(l))
    ind = len(srt[0])
    for ele in srt:
        d[ele[:ind]].append(ele)
    for val in d.values():
        for v in val:
            # check each substring in the sublist
            if not any(v.startswith(s) and v != s for s in val):
                yield v


print(list(find_with_dupe(l)))

['abfdsdg', 'abed', 'abb', 'd', 'sdfdg', 'xc']
```

Which run on a random sample of text runs in a fraction of the time your own code does:

```
In [15]: l = open("/home/padraic/Downloads/sample.txt").read().split()

In [16]: timeit list(find(l))                                         
100 loops, best of 3: 19 ms per loop

In [17]: %%timeit
   ....: l = open("/home/padraic/Downloads/sample.txt").read().split()
   ....: for i in range(0, len(l) - 1):
   ....:     for j in range(i + 1, len(l)):
   ....:         if l[j].startswith(l[i]):
   ....:             l[j] = l[i]
   ....:         else:
   ....:             if l[i].startswith(l[j]):
   ....:                 l[i] = l[j]
   ....: 

1 loops, best of 3: 4.92 s per loop
```

Both returning identical output:

```
In [41]: l = open("/home/padraic/Downloads/sample.txt").read().split()

In [42]:  
for i in range(0, len(l) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(l)):
        if l[j].startswith(l[i]):
            l[j] = l[i]
        else:
            if l[i].startswith(l[j]):
                l[i] = l[j]
   ....:                 


In [43]: 

In [43]: l2 = open("/home/padraic/Downloads/sample.txt").read().split()

In [44]: sorted(set(l)) == sorted(find(l2))
Out[44]: True
```

Comment: Hi Padraic. Would you be kind enough to test my answer? I would like to see how it stacks up against the others with the same data and on the same machine.

Comment: +1 for nice examples. I have tested your examples with and works fine with small input data. If data input are increasing the the execution is increased exponential . Also this doesn't catch the duplicates.

Comment: @vasilenicusor, the last part definitely does catch dupes. The counter dict counts all occurrences of words and no word appearing twice is yielded. What are you running it on?

Comment: this script should get from a big list with file paths only the unique root paths (files of folders). e.g ['a:/dir1','a:/dir1/file1.txt','a:/dir1/dir2','a:/dir4/file4.tx', 'a:/dir4/file4.txt'] the result is ['a:/dir1','a:/dir4/file4.tx']

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham to get sample data for testing the script, use a list with paths from your HDD - i use dir "C:\*" /s/b > e:/out.txt then load each line from out.tx in list. In my situation i have 1498136 files. and the script are still running after 10 minutes :)  with  214 MB RAM and 30% CPU  on a PC with I5 3.2 GHz and 16 GB RAM

Comment: @vasilenicusor,  what size are all those files, you realize reading an enormous amount of data will take a long time? You could use multiprocessing to speed up the process but  `1498136 ` is a lot of files!

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham the reading of the file, 161 MB, on my PC takes around 2 seconds from a SSD HDD. Not the reading is the problem, the filtering.

Comment: @vasilenicusor, so the whole file is 161MB?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham YES, and the script are still runningg

Comment: can you upload the file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77665/discussion-between-vasilenicusor-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 4):

**Edit3**
After some meditation I wrote this algorithm. It is 1k times faster than the `reduce`-based method based on the big random data set provided by Padraic Cunningham (thanks for the set). The algorithm has ~ O(nlogn) complexity, though there is some space left for minor optimization. It's also very memory efficient. It takes roughly n additional space.

```
def my_filter(l):
    q = sorted(l, reverse=True)
    first = q.pop()
    addfirst = True
    while q:
        candidate = q.pop()
        if candidate == first:
            addfirst = False
            continue
        if not candidate.startswith(first):
            if addfirst:
                yield first
            first, addfirst = candidate, True
    if addfirst:
        yield first
```

**Edit2** This thing is as fast as the `reduce`-based algorithm in my tests, but this comparison depends on the data set used. I simply parsed a text-book page into words. The algorithm is based on the following observation. Let A, B and C be strings, len(A) < min(len(B), len(C)). Observe that if A is a prefix of B it's sufficient to check if A is a prefix of C to say that there is a prefix of C.

```
def my_filter(l):
    q = sorted(l, key=len)
    prefixed = []
    while q:
        candidate = q.pop()
        if any(candidate.startswith(prefix) for prefix in prefixed):
            continue
        if any(candidate.startswith(string) for string in q):
            prefixed.append(candidate)
        else:
           yield candidate
```

**Original post**
This is the original algorithm I proposed. in fact it's a concise version of your algorithm.

```
l = ['ab', 'xc', 'abb', 'abed', 'sdfdg', 'abfdsdg', 'xccc']

res = [string for string in l if sum(not string.startswith(prefix) for prefix in l) == len(l)-1]
```

Demo>>>

```
print res
# ['ab', 'xc', 'sdfdg']
```

Comment: This takes `11.3 s` for 7k strings

Comment: @PadraicCunningham How do you produce the 7K strings?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham How much time does it take code of the question?

Comment: In my test my code takes far less than a second to run OP's list 10k times. And I know the complexity of my algorithm is O(n^2).

Comment: @EliKorvigo How do you know your comlexity  is O(n^2)?

Comment: @TonyYang it makes n comparisons for each of n items in the list. That is roughly n^2 in the big O notation. P.S. I don't take into account the cost of the `startswith` operation itself, taking it as constant (O(1))

Comment: @EliKorvigo, you mean your tests on a list with 7 elements?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yeah, that it is a dummy test because the complexity is not linear.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Actually I though of utilizing the De Bruijn graph. One might obtain the graph and find isolated vertices. That would be beautiful, though slow.

Comment: @EliKorvigo, yep, any naive approach is going to be slow, the reduce function is also takes a long time to finish.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  I've added another algorithm I would be glad if you test it with your data set.

Comment: @EliKorvigo, added the output, a little bit slower than reduce but it does give the correct answer

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I made a new version that is faster than reduce in my tests.

Comment: @EliKorvigo, `2.17 s per loop`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I pasted a wrong version. Now there is the faster version.

Comment: identical amount of time again

Comment: @PadraicCunningham This problem received ridiculous amount of my attention :D Nevertheless I came up with a linear algorithm (if you don't count sorting complexity). I would be glad  to know your opinion about it.

Comment: His solution gives the same results as ours and is a clear winner on speed (ours are about the same)

Comment: `>>> print t4.timeit(number=3)`  
`2.35278606415`  
`>>> print t3.timeit(number=3)`  
`22.0751419067`  
`>>> print t2.timeit(number=3)`  
`15.3550701141`  
`>>> print t1.timeit(number=3)`  
`9.87976694107`  

t1 and t2 are mine (I was experimenting with checking high to low str length or vise versa), t3 is yours and t4 is Eli's.  I upped the length of the input list to 500k to see how they scaled. At 5k ours are the same speed.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I can't even work out how yours works but it is simple and fast, nice one

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the solution handles duplicates.

Comment: @skolsuper Thanks a lot. I can explain the idea. Observe that in a lexicographically ordered array of strings there exist subarrays [a-z] such that each subarray begins with a prefix of all strings in the subarray. The only thing left to do is to pick these prefixes. This operation takes ~ O(n) time + time needed to sort the initial array.

Comment: Ah yes now I see it. Taking advantage of the fact that 'ba' comes before 'aab' in string sorting, so you know you only need to check the ones after, and throw them out as you go. And reverse order makes it that much faster because long strings are discarded first, we take the easy wins. Quick question: are you a python programmer normally? Maybe my instant recourse to fancy data types is a flaw in my thinking I need to work on.

Comment: @skolsuper I'm not a professional programmer at all. I'm a bioinformatics PhD student and, though we all study 3-4 languages(Python, R, C/C++, SQL), I'm not the one to judge your expertise :)

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = ['ab', 'xc', 'abb', 'abed', 'sdfdg', 'abfdsdg', 'xccc']
result = []

for element in lst:
  is_prefixed = False
  for possible_prefix in lst:
    if element is not possible_prefix and element.startswith(possible_prefix):
      is_prefixed = True
      break
  if not is_prefixed:
    result.append(element)
```

### Here is some experimental, multithreaded version:

**Test it well!**

```
import thread
import math
import multiprocessing

list = ['ab', 'xc', 'abb', 'abed', 'sdfdg', 'abfdsdg', 'xccc']

def get_results(list, thread_num, num_of_threads):  
  result = []
  part_size = int(math.ceil(len(list) * 1.0 / num_of_threads))
  for element in list[part_size * thread_num: part_size * (thread_num + 1)]:    
    is_prefixed = False
    for possible_prefix in list:
      if element is not possible_prefix and     element.startswith(possible_prefix):
    is_prefixed = True
    if not is_prefixed:
      result.append(element)
  return result

num_of_threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
results = []
for t in xrange(num_of_threads):  
  thread.start_new_thread(lambda list: results.extend(get_results(list, t, num_of_threads)), (list,))
```

Comment: takes 8 seconds for a list with 7k stings

Comment: Now it is  `2.96 s per loop`

Comment: Is it enough? How often do You need to run it?

Comment: Your code seems to check all of the possible prefixes. My goes to next element after first prefix is matched

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import Counter


def filter_list(mylist):

    longest_string = len(max(mylist, key=len))

    set_list = [set(filter(lambda x: len(x) == i, mylist))
                for i in range(1, longest_string)]

    def unique_starts_with_filter(string):
        for i in range(1, len(string)):
            if string[:i] in set_list[i-1]: return False
        return True

    cn = Counter(mylist)
    mylist = filter(lambda x: cn[x] == 1, mylist)

    return filter(unique_starts_with_filter, mylist)
```

Edited (again) for style and very minor optimizations

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it would be cool if you could test this for me with the same data and machine as the others.  I think it should be O(n)

Comment: Okay thanks very much. Rather than debug it, I think I will just leave it there as your answer is very thorough. I'd be surprised if the nut implementation doesn't involve a set somewhere though as membership tests are O(1) (same for defaultdict though I guess?)

Comment: yours works well if there are no dupes like my first answer. The problem with using a set or a dict is that if a word appears twice it will be counted as unique, if you added a counter check as per my answer I imagine yours should also cover all cases

Comment: Aren't dupes supposed to be removed? To my mind, 'abc' starts with 'abc'

Comment: yes but you are not removing them. If you have two `"abc"'s` your code will keep one

Comment: Oh I should remove both? Yeah you're right a Counter would be the way to go then

Comment: `"abc".startswith("abc") -> True`, unless the OP only wants to consider substring matches then yes it should be removed, I left a few different versions because the full implementation details are not known

Comment: Quite interesting. Have you analysed memory consumption? `set`s and `Counter`s being hash-tables have huge memory impact. Nevertheless, if memory is not an issue, this is a good approach.

Comment: doesn't work  with  `['abbb', 'xc', 'abb', 'abed', 'sdfdg', 'xc','abfdsdg', 'xccc', 'd','dd','sdfdg', 'xc','abfdsdg', 'xccc', 'd','dd']`

Comment: @vasilenicusor, your own code outputs `['abed', 'abfdsdg', 'xc', 'd', 'sdfdg', 'abb']` which is wrong so what should the output be?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham why is wrong my output? please check again. the output is valid

Comment: @vasilenicusor, everything bar `['abb', 'abed']` is either a dupe or has a prefix that matches another string, are you saying `"dd".startswith("dd")` should be False?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham "dd".startswith("dd") should be false only if "dd" is the same element with "dd" (same position) else should be true

Comment: but there are other dd's in different positions of the list so by that logic it should not appear, if that is what you actually want as output that makes my code even more efficient as you can call set on the list with my first code and it will give you `['abfdsdg', 'abed', 'abb', 'd', 'xc', 'sdfdg']`, you don't need a counter at all

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham I know how to fix this. I still searching for a good and fast solution.

Comment: @vasilenicusor, you will have to provide some real input samples, my edited code runs in a fractions of the time yours does and returns exactly the same output, if that does not work for you I will need a real sample.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham now i will make last test. Its true that run fast. After tests, if pass, i will accep the answer. you are really good ;)

Comment: @vasilenicusor. No worries. If there are failures then add the data it failed on so we can all have something to work with.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1** (Using LinkedList)

Here is a very simple solution using sorting (`O(n * log(n))`) and `LinkedList` - iterating (`O(n)`) and removing elements (`O(1)`). If you sort the initial data, the elements are going to be ordered in such way that the longest prefix element for another element, is going to be adjacent to the later. Thus that element may be removed.

Here is a code that filters out a sorted `LinkedList`:

```
def filter_out(the_list):
    for element in the_list:
        if element.prev_node and element.get_data().startswith(element.prev_node.get_data()):
            the_list.remove(element)

    return the_list
```

And use it like this:

```
linked_list = LinkedList(sorted(l))
filter_out(linked_list)
```

Then your `linked_list` will contain the filtered data.

This solution will take `O(n * log(n))`

And here is the implementation of `LinkedList`:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None, prev_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self._next_node = next_node
        self._prev_node = prev_node

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    @property
    def next_node(self):
        return self._next_node

    @next_node.setter
    def next_node(self, node):
        self._next_node = node

    @property
    def prev_node(self):
        return self._prev_node

    @prev_node.setter
    def prev_node(self, node):
        self._prev_node = node

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.get_data())


class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        super(LinkedList, self).__init__()

        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.size = 0

        if iterable:
            for element in iterable:
                self.insert(Node(element))

    def insert(self, node):
        if self.head:
            self.tail.next_node = node
            node.prev_node = self.tail
            self.tail = node
        else:
            self.head = node
            self.tail = node

        self.size += 1

    def remove(self, node):
        if self.size > 1:
            prev_node = node.prev_node
            next_node = node.next_node

            if prev_node:
                prev_node.next_node = next_node
            if next_node:
                next_node.prev_node = prev_node
        else:
            self.head = None
            self.tail = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return LinkedListIter(self.head)

    def __repr__(self):
        result = ''
        for node in self:
            result += str(node.get_data()) + ', '
        if result:
            result = result[:-2]
        return "[{}]".format(result)


class LinkedListIter(object):
    def __init__(self, start):
        super(LinkedListIter, self).__init__()

        self.node = start

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        this_node = self.node

        if not this_node:
            raise StopIteration

        self.node = self.node.next_node
        return this_node
```

**Solution 2** (Using set)

If the algorithm is not required to be stable, i.e. the resulting list needs not to keep the original order of the elements, here is a solution using `set`.

So let us make some definitions:

> **`n`** - the size of your list, i.e. number of elements
>
> **`m`** - the maximum possible length of a string element of your list

First of all, initialise a new `set` `inter` out of your original `list` `l`:

```
inter = set(l)
```

by this we will remove all the duplicate elements, which will ease our further work. Also, this operation will take `O(n)` complexity in average and `O(n^2)` in worst case.

Then make another empty `set` where we will keep our results:

```
result = set()
```

So now let us check for each of the elements, whether there is a suffix for it in our `inter` set:

```
for elem in inter:                   # This will take at most O(n)
    no_prefix = True
    for i in range(1, len(elem)):    # This will take at most O(m)
        if elem[:i] in inter:        # This will take avg: O(1), worst: O(n)
            no_prefix = False
            continue

    if no_prefix:
        result.add(elem)             # This will take avg: O(1), worst: O(n)
```

So now you have got what you wanted in the `result`.

This final and core step will take `O(n * (1 * m + 1)) = O(n * m)` in average and `O(n * (m * n + n)) = O(n^2 * (m + 1))` in worst case, thus if `m` is insignificant compared to `n` then you have the `O(n)` in average and `O(n ^ 2)` in worst case.

The complexities are calculated based on what [Python provides for the `set` data structure](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). To further optimise the algorithm, you can implement your own `tree-based set` and gain `O(n * log(n))` complexity.

Comment: 53.2039999962 seconds with the provided demo input on PC with 3.2 Ghz, i5, 16 GB RAM. Nice solution

Comment: @vasilenicusor what is your best result so far?

Comment: optimized, see Solution 1, takes about 10 secs on your data.

Comment: till now, the best solution is the solution provided by @Benoit Esnard   with `0.582999944687 seconds`

Answer (score 3):

I believe the following could very likely be the most efficient.

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet
def prefixes(l) :
    rtn = SortedSet()
    for s in l:
        rtn.add(s)
        i = rtn.index(s)
        if (i > 0 and s.startswith(rtn[i-1])):
            rtn.remove(s)
        else :
            j = i+1
            while (j < len(rtn) and rtn[j].startswith(s)):
                j+=1
            remove = rtn[i+1:j]
            for r in remove:
                rtn.remove(r)
    return list(rtn)
```

I believe the most important case is probably really long input files, with much smaller output files. This solution avoids holding the entire input file in memory. If the input file is sorted, then it never holds a rtn argument longer than the eventual returned file. Moreover, it demonstrates the pattern of "maintain a solution that is valid for data seen so far, and extend this solution to be valid to each new piece of data". This is a nice pattern to familiarize yourself with.

Comment: Good solution. ~10 seconds  for sample input and ~18 seconds if input list is shuffled

Comment: How does that stack up against the others? I think if you create a super big input file  that still has a reasonable sized output file (say, by concatinating  your file together many times) mine will still scale well. The answer you accepted requires the ability to hold the entire input file in memory, whereas mine will hold something more like the output file in memory).

Comment: In other words, this solution will run on any iterable, including a generator.

Comment: It's true, but this list is not loaded from a file,it is builded at runtime. I posted this  file only for testing and to give an overview about the amount of data from input list.

Comment: Sure. But we should try to address this problem in general. I believe for the case where the input set is massive, but the output set is reasonable, this solution will be the best. This is an important case to consider, as massive data is a real thing.

Comment: As I told in my question `The filter function must be fast ....` I don't contest your solution, is a good solution, for this i give vote up.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using the reduce function:

```
def r(a, b):
    if type(a) is list:
        if len([z for z in a if b.startswith(z)]) == 0:
            a.append(b)
        return a
    if a.startswith(b):
        return b
    if b.startswith(a):
        return a
    return [a, b]

print reduce(r, l)
```

Probably, the `[z for z in a if b.startswith(z)]` part can be further optimized.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this short solution.

```
import re
l = ['ab', 'xc', 'abb', 'abed', 'sdfdg', 'abfdsdg', 'xccc']
newl=[]
newl.append(l[0])
con=re.escape(l[0])

for i in l[1:]:
    pattern=r"^(?!(?:"+con+r")).*$"
    if re.match(pattern,i):
        newl.append(i)
        con=con+"|"+re.escape(i)


print newl
```

EDIT:For long lists use

```
import re
l = ['ab', 'xc', 'abb', 'abed', 'sdfdg', 'abfdsdg', 'xccc']
newl=[]
newl.append(l[0])
con=re.escape(l[0])

for i in l[1:]:
    for x in re.split("\|",con):
        pattern=r"^(?="+x+r").*$"
        if re.match(pattern,i):
            break
    else:
        newl.append(i)
        con=con+"|"+re.escape(i)


print newl
```

Comment: Hi, this work OK with simple string,  but don't work with string like  `C:\~sqltmp\express\xmlrw.dll` the regex pattern will be `^(?!(?:C:\~sqltmp\express\xmlrw.dll)).*$`  and will raise error `invalid expression` , `sre_constants.error: bogus escape: '\\x'`

Comment: because the size of `con` are increasing fast, after 582 iteration the length of `pattern` is 39615 and will raise `OverflowError` `regular expression code size limit exceeded`. For testing use sample data from http://soft2u.ro/out.txt

Comment: because the solution is limited by the size of input data. See my previous comment. Please add fix to your solution and down vote will be removed

Comment: Now looks more better

Comment: please take in consideration that using regex is time consuming. this script are still running after 15 minutes with sample demo input from http://soft2u.ro/out.txt :(