# Given a list of string, determine if one string is a prefix of another string

Tags: python

I want to write a Python function which checks if one string is a prefix string of another; not an arbitrary sub string of another; must be prefix. If it is, return True. For instance,

```
list = ['abc', 'abcd', 'xyx', 'mno']
```

Return `True` because `'abc'` is a prefix of `'abcd'`.

```
list = ['abc', 'xyzabc', 'mno']
```

Return `False`

I tried the `startwith()` and list comprehension, but it didn't quite work.
Appreciate for any help or pointers.

Comment: Please include the code you have tried. Does it work? If not, what doesn't work?

Comment: `one string is a prefix string of another` ? which one string you are talking about ?

Comment: Also, it's best not to name an object `list` you'll mask the builtin by the same name

Comment: So the goal is to find out if any string in a list is a prefix of any other string in the same list?

Comment: definitely a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186869/obtain-a-list-containing-string-elements-excluding-elements-prefixed-with-any-ot/30269492#30269492). Please research before posting a question.

Comment: @n9code: How do you know that I didn't do a research before posting the question?

Comment: What I want is this: Given a list, determine if there's any string which is a substring of others, not of itself. This time it doesn't have to be prefix.

['abc', 'mabc', 'xyz', 'mnq']  --> True
['abc', 'abcm', 'xyz', 'mnq']  --> True
['abc', 'abc', 'xyz', 'mnq']  --> True
['abc', 'mlxs', 'xyz', 'mnq']  --> False

Comment: @user1972031 saying research I mean find an already existing question/answer. E.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186869/obtain-a-list-containing-string-elements-excluding-elements-prefixed-with-any-ot/30269492#30269492)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first sort the given `lst` w.r.t length of the string, due to the known fact that sub strings always have length less than or equal to the original string, so after sorting we have strings with smaller length at the start of the list, and then we iterate over the sorted list comparing the current element with all the elements next to it, This small optimization would reduce the complexity of the problem as now we don't have to comapre each element with every other element.

```
lst1 = ['abc', 'abcd', 'xyx', 'mno']
lst2 = ['abc', 'xyzabc', 'mno']
lst3 = ["abc", "abc"]

def check_list(lst):
    lst = list(set(lst))    #if you want to avoid redundant strings.
    lst.sort(key = lambda x:len(x))

    n = len(lst)
    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(i+1, n):
            if lst[j].startswith(lst[i]):
                return True
    return False

print check_list(lst1)
print check_list(lst2)
print check_list(lst3)
>>> True
>>> False
>>> False #incase you use lst = list(set(lst))
```

Comment: I don't think that prefix has length strictly less than the original string. For example `abc` is a prefix of `abc`.

Comment: But in the example given, the user is matching `abc` to `abcd` in the first case and not matching `abc` to `abc` otherwise the answer would be True for any case, I agree that `abc` is a prefix of `abc` but I have made this assumption in context to the question asked . @geckon

Comment: So you only assume your solution to work for the exact list posted in the question then?

Comment: Thank you anmol_uppal for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools`

```
import itertools

list1 = ["abc", "xyz", "abc123"]
products = itertools.product(list1, list1)
is_substringy = any(x.startswith(y) for x, y in products if x != y)
```

This isn't very optimised, but depending on the amount of data you've got to deal with, the code is fairly elegant (and short); that might trump speed in your use case.

This assumes that you don't have pure repeats in the list however (but you don't have that in your example).

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
mlist = ['abc', 'abcd', 'xyx', 'mno']
#combination of list elements, 2-by-2. without repetition  
In [638]: for i,j in itertools.combinations(mlist,2):
    print (i,j)
   .....:     
('abc', 'abcd')
('abc', 'xyx')
('abc', 'mno')
('abcd', 'xyx')
('abcd', 'mno')
('xyx', 'mno')
#r holds the final result. if there is any pair where one is a prefixed of another 
r=False
In [639]: for i,j in itertools.combinations(mlist,2):  
    r = r or i.startswith(j) # if i is the prefix of j. logical or
    r = r or j.startswith(i) # if j is the prefix of i
   .....:     

In [640]: r
Out[640]: True
```

Comment: Needs an explanation.

Comment: Worked for my simple case, see new requirements above. Thanks much.