# Remove items from list that are substrings of other items in the same list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, substring

Python 3:

I have a list of words. I want to create a dict that contains unique words from the list as key and their frequency as value. Also I want to remove any words that are substrings of other words from the list.

For eg:

```
list  =   ['goon ', 'goonk ', 'goon ', 'goonj ', 'w ', 'wo ', 'wor ', 'world ', 'world ']
```

Dictionary should be :

```
dict  =  {'goonj': 1, 'world': 2, 'goonk':1}
```

I have tried the following methods but I do not get the desired dict.

Method 1: If the substring list for key is empty then I add that key to the dict.

```
for keyword in list:         
    if not [key for key in list if keyword in key and key != keyword]:
        if keyword in KeywordDict:
            KeywordDict[keyword] += 1
        else:
            KeywordDict[keyword] = 1
```

Method 2: Add the word to dict and remove all it's substring keys from dict.

```
if keyword in KeywordDict:
    KeywordDict[keyword] += 1
else:
    KeywordDict[keyword] = 1
for key in KeywordDict:
    if keyword.startswith(key) > -1:
        KeywordDict.pop(key)
```

I have tried other minor variations of the above methods but the list still contains words that are substrings.

The actual list has about 300 words.

I have also tried using list comprehension and dict comprehension with the   same bug.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: What about `goonk` ?

Comment: [Delete substrings from your list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221878/python-delete-substrings-from-list-of-strings) and then [count the occurences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item) of what's left. These are really two completely independent problems.

Comment: composite dupiicates are okay as I heard.

Comment: Your strings contain spaces at the end, there are no substrings of others in your list. To remove the spaces do `lst = list(map(str.strip, lst))`

Comment: goonk also. My mistake. I'lll add it to the list.