# Check if element of list is sub-element of other list elements in same list

Tags: python, list

I am looking for a way to check if an element of a list is sub-element of any other elements of that same list?

For example, let's use the below list as an example.

```
['Lebron James', 'Lebron', 'James']
```

The 2nd and 3rd elements of this list are a sub-element of the 1st element of the list.

I am looking for a way to remove these elements from the list so only the 1st element remains. I have been spinning my wheels and unable to come up with a solution.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: @yatu no, the number of elements in the list can vary.

Comment: No, but the solution from @Alex below works well

Comment: Does it have to match a whole word in the longer string, or any substring? E.g. should the 2nd element of `['Lebron James', 'Le']` be returned?

Comment: I hadn't thought about this, but it probably should be whole match. Good point- do you have any thoughts on how to modify the solution below?

Comment: also: [Remove items from list that are substrings of other items in the same list \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49872752/674039)

Comment: Use `split()` to split up the long string, and test whether the word is in that list.

Comment: @ZakRaySick You should add that requirement to the question.

Comment: @wim I reopened since the comment says he wants to match whole words, not substrings. Do you have a more appropriate dup before I post an answer?

Comment: I thought about my question a little more and am going to reframe it.

Comment: @Barmar  Meh, whether the "membership" is via substring or tuple member or overlapping range that does not significantly change the problem (nor the solutions) IMO.

Comment: @wim I think it changes it significantly, especially if you want to avoid n**2 solutions.

Comment: O.P.  Have a look at intervaltree datastructure e.g. [Python representation for a set of non-overlapping integer ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50592912/674039)

Comment: And I'm usually pretty liberal about what constitutes a duplicate when I close them.

Comment: What about `['Lebron James 1 2 3', 'Lebron James 1 2']`? Keep both or filter out the second? Or not relevant?

Comment: I've reverted the last edit since it seems to make it a completely different question. You should have posted a new question instead of editing this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slow solution, might be acceptable depending on your data size:

```
lst = ['Lebron James', 'Lebron', 'James']
[s for s in lst if not any(s in s2.split() for s2 in lst if s != s2)]
```

Comment: looks unnecessarily O(n**2)

Comment: @wim That's why he said it's a slow solution. It will get slower when he addresses the comment that the OP just wants to match whole words, not any substring.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an easier problem to tackle with the starting and ending points for the match instead of the strings themselves.

One approach can be to take all ranges from biggest to smallest, and work backwards, creating the result as you go, given a range is not fully contained in another.

```
lst = [(0, 10),(0, 4),(5, 10)]

result = []

def membership(big_range, small_range):
    '''return true if big_range fully contains the small_range.
    where both are tuples with a start and end value.
    '''
    if small_range[0] >= big_range[0] and small_range[1] <= big_range[1]:
        return True
    return False

for range_ in sorted(lst, key= lambda x: x[1] - x[0], reverse=True):
    if not any(membership(x, range_) for x in result):
        result.append(range_)

print(result)
#[(0, 10)]
```

Edit: this answer was in response to the OP'S edited question, which seems to have since been rolled back. Oh well. Hope it helps someone anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Can try to create a dictionary of all permutations (the choice between permutations, or sublists, or whatever, depends on the desired behavior) grouped by element's word count:

```
import re
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [
    'Lebron Raymone James', 'Lebron Raymone', 
    'James', "Le", "Lebron James", 
    'Lebron James 1 2 3', 'Lebron James 1 2'
]

d = defaultdict(dict)
g = "\\b\w+\\b"

for x in lst:
    words = re.findall(g, x)  # could simply use x.split() if have just spaces
    combos = [
        x for i in range(1, len(words) + 1)
        for x in list(itertools.permutations(words, i))
    ]
    for c in combos:
        d[len(words)][tuple(c)] = True
```

and take just elements whose words are not present in any of the groups with greater words count:

```
M = max(d) 
res = []
for x in lst:
    words = tuple(re.findall(g, x))
    if not any(d[i].get(words) for i in range(len(words)+1, M+1)):
        res.append(x)
set(res)
# {'Le', 'Lebron James 1 2 3', 'Lebron Raymone James'}
```

Answer (score -2):

Create a set containing all the words in the strings that are multiple words. Then go through the list, testing the strings to see if they're in the set.

```
wordset = set()
lst = ['Lebron James', 'Lebron', 'James']
for s in lst:
    if " " in s:
        wordset.update(s.split())
result = [x for x in lst if x not in wordset]
```

Comment: Your algorithm is bad.  Consider input `['Lebron James 1 2 3', 'Lebron James 1 2']`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's something he wants to filter out, we should ask.